# Problemas com NA em R

Tags: r

Boa noite a todos, quero escrever uma função em R que verifique os elementos pares e exibá-os em tela depois. A partir disso escrevi o seguinte código:

```
pares <- function(v){
    for(i in v){
        if ((v[i]%%2)==0){
        b[i]<-c(v[i])
    }
}
print(b)

}
pares(a)
```

com isso recebi a seguinte resposta do compilador:
[1]  0  2 NA  4 NA  6 NA  8 NA 10
Não sei qual a causa disso, alguém poderia me ajudar a remover esses "NA"?
Muito obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está confundindo no código fazer o loop com um contador e um loop de array. Quando se faz o `for i in v`, cada vez que o loop roda ele roda ele coloca o valor do próximo valor de v em `i`.

A forma correta seria:

```
pares <- function(v){
    for(i in v){
        if ((i%%2)==0){
        b <- append(b, i)
    }
}
print(b)
}
```